# Deploying a Rails / Ember app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having issues deploying my elastic beanstalk rails 4 + ember cli app. I have a rails application and within the root I have a folder called 'frontend' which contains my ember app generated by ember CLI Rails.

My configuration:
64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.1 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)

I encounter the following error from my activity log after I run eb deploy:

At cursory, I get this

```
ERROR: Instance: i-25c139e7 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...mber-cli-rails.rb:58:in `compile!'
```

Looking into /var/log/eb-activity.log

I first get a lot of 
    npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock X, which hasn't been locked

followed by
    npm ERR! System Linux 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64
    npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd /var/app/ondeck/frontend
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR! /var/app/ondeck/frontend/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
    rake aborted!
    EmberCLI Rails requires your Ember app to have an addon.

```
From within your EmberCLI directory please run:

$ npm install --save-dev ember-cli-rails-addon@0.0.11

in you Ember application root: /var/app/ondeck/frontend

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => ember:compile
(See full trace by running task with --trace) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

So I ssh into the directory indicated and run npm install, which also leaves me with a lot of errors regarding authorization. When I run with via sudo, the modules install correctly, but when I redeploy my app, it gives me the exact same error.

I have tried sudo NPM install and chown -R node_modules webapp so that the node_modules folder can be accessed by the webapp group with no success.

Comment: Having the same problem myself.  Ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes. SSH into your Elastic Beanstalk instance, mkdir webapp on ~/../ and run "chown -u webapp:webapp ~/../webapp". I think ember was expecting a root directory webapp with the proper permissions for user webapp.

Comment: Yes, that makes some sense.  I think `npm` was trying to lock some files in the `webapp` user's home directory, and I had noticed earlier today that the webapp user didn't have a home directory, but I didn't both to create one.  I worry that this fix approach won't work should the app attempt to load-scale to another fresh instance.  Any experience there?

Comment: Good point. It'll be a good idea to include the mkdir command within the EB config file when instances are spun up, but I am just throwing a hypothesis.

Comment: Also if you want the load balancer to create a home directory for webapp on deploy for any instance, include something like this within container_commands of your .config file under .ebextensions container_command: "sudo rm -r -f ~/../webapp; sudo mkdir ~/../webapp; sudo chown webapp:webapp ~/../webapp" . This should be executed bfore app deployment for any instance, I believe. Testing it now..

Comment: Yeah, I've got what appears to be a working solution now.  I'll post my .ebextensions customizations as an answer to this question.  Thanks again Tim.

Comment: That'll be really helpful. I am still trying to fight EB, can't seem to get frontend.js and frontend.css to work. Rails server is good, but it seems like Ember-cli-rails does not compile/build ember properly. I'm playing around with the post deploy scripts, let me know what you come up with.

Answer (score 8):

I hate long answers, but this scenario is quite complicated.

As mentioned in the comments above, it was discovered that the *home directory* for the *webapp* user needed to be created (`/home/webapp`).  Once this directory is created, the node package manager (npm) can execute without error.  Because AWSEB environments can scale, SSH'ing into the EB host and performing one-off installations of packages and modules will not work in the long run.  Essentially the answer boils down to the following logical steps:

1. Install git on the application server because bower needs it.
2. Create the home directory of the `webapp` user at `/home/webapp`.
3. Install bower globally using npm.
4. Invoke the `npm install` of your ember app.
5. Invoke `bower install` for your ember app.

To fix this I went ahead and created several `.ebextensions` customization files that are executed during an `eb deploy`.  Here they are in order:

1. `.ebextensions/00_option_settings.config` - sets some EB options; for example the timeout length for command executions performed during an `eb deploy`.  In this case all *commands* will timeout after 1200 seconds.

   ```
   option_settings:
     - namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:command'
       option_name: 'Timeout'
       value: '1200'
   ```
2. `.ebextensions/01_packages.config` - can install packages through *yum* and make them available to your eb instance.  In this case I use yum to install git, this will later be used by bower.

   ```
   packages:
     yum:
       git: []
   ```
3. `.ebextensions/02_commands.config` - allows you to run OS commands prior to unpacking the application that was uploaded through `eb deploy`.  *This part of the answer satisfies the main theme of this question:* In my particular case, I need to create the `/home/webapp` directory, make sure it is owned by the `webapp` user, and also has 700 permissions.  Lastly, I ensure that bower is installed globally as it will be needed by my ember application.

   ```
   commands:
     01_mkdir_webapp_dir:
       # use the test directive to create the directory
       # if the mkdir command fails the rest of this directive is ignored
       test: 'mkdir /home/webapp'
       command: 'ls -la /home/webapp'
     02_chown_webapp_dir:
       command: 'chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp'
     03_chmod_webapp_dir:
       command: 'chmod 700 /home/webapp'
     04_install_bower_global:
       command: 'npm install -g bower'
   ```
4. `.ebextensions/03_container_commands.config` - runs OS command after the application has been unpacked.  *NOTE:* My ember app lives in the `frontend` directory of application source code.  In order to install the npm and bower dependencies, the `npm install` and `bower install` commands need to be executed from the *frontend* directory.  It is also worth mentioning that the bower-install command needs the `--allow-root` flag in order to succeed as the AWS user executing these commands has elevated privileges.

   ```
   container_commands:
     01_npm_install:
       # set the current working directory to fully-qualified frontend
       cwd: '/var/app/ondeck/frontend/'
       command: 'npm install'
       leader_only: 'false'
     02_bower_install:
       # set the current working directory to fully-qualified frontend
       cwd: '/var/app/ondeck/frontend/'
       command: 'bower --allow-root install'
       leader_only: 'false'
     03_seeddb:
       # seed my database (has nothing to do with this answer)
       command: 'rake db:seed_fu'
       leader_only: 'true'
   ```

Comment: Works like a charm. I also added a script to start a resque worker using monit which is unrelated. You rock!